# Reduce if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

I have 3 `define` statements:

```
#define LOCATION_SEA 1
#define LOCATION_AIR 2
#define LOCATION_GROUND 3
```

I have two methods of checking a particular variable against those `define`s:

```
int IsLocationGround(TreeNode *node)
{
 return (node->node_type == LOCATION_GROUND);
}

int IsAnyLocation(TreeNode *node)
{
 return (node->node_type == LOCATION_GROUND ||
         node->node_type == LOCATION_AIR    ||
         node->node_type == LOCATION_SEA );
}
```

and in part of my code I am doing this:

```
if (IsLocationGround(node))
  statements A.....
else if (IsAnyLocation(node))
  statements B.....
else 
  statements C
```

As functions IsLocationGround() and IsAnyLocation() are quite close to each other, is it possible to change it in such a way I will use only 1 if-else block?

Comment: I don't think so, and what's the reason to do it?!! You have 3 different blocks  to execute!

Edit : Mat got me :)

Comment: A minor performance improvement would be to do the `node->node_type == LOCATION_GROUND` last in the `IsAnyLocation()`, given that this will have already been tested for in the first branch of the if, and will be short circuited.

Comment: Use `switch(node.node_type)` in your calling function and then you wouldn't need any if else block

Comment: Why not use a `switch`?

Comment: You could use an array of function pointers and just `funarr[node->node_type]()` but depending on your "statements" that may also be unnecessary since the data with those blocks could be refactored into arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard C/UNIX way to to this kind of thing *if the categories are not exclusive* is to use bitmasks. I made the functions `static`, which can seduce the compiler to get them inlined.

```
#define LOCATION_SEA 1
#define LOCATION_AIR 2
#define LOCATION_GROUND 4
#define LOCATION_ALL ( LOCATION_SEA | LOCATION_AIR | LOCATION_GROUND )

static int IsLocationGround(TreeNode *node)
{
 return (node->node_type & LOCATION_GROUND);
}

static int IsAnyLocation(TreeNode *node)
{
 return (node->node_type & LOCATION_ALL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the `if`/`else if`/`else` code *and* the functions `IsLocationGround`/`IsAnyLocation` with this equivalent code:

```
switch (node->node_type) {
  case LOCATION_GROUND:
    statements A.....
    break;
  case LOCATION_AIR:
  case LOCATION_SEA:
    statements B.....
    break;
  default:
    statements C.....
}
```